# to keep or to keeping

Tags: sentence-construction, verb-forms

I have problem with grammatical structure of following sentence.

> Several layers of thin clothing are essential to keeping warm.

Shouldn't be "to keep"? why "keeping"?

Comment: @Rathony Thanks a lot for ur help but I couldn't find my answer. Nope, I just ask it as another question.

Comment: Don't expect to get an answer here. Your question will be closed.

Comment: @Rathony sorry, what was the problem with my question?

Comment: Not all uses of _to_ mark infinitives. You're looking at the wrong chunk; _to keeping warm_ is not a constituent. The _to_ is part of the constituent  _be essential to_, and _keeping warm_ is a gerund phrase (another constituent) that is the object of the preposition _to_.  A basic principle of syntax is that syntactic rules apply only to constituents, and **not** to random strings of words that happen to occur together. So you have to locate the constituents before you can even ask a reasonable question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- "keeping" is used as a *gerund* which makes "keeping warm" a *noun phrase*.  As such, it can be introduced by the *preposition* "to" (or "for".)
- " to keep" is the infinitive form, wherein "to" is simply *part of the infinitive*.  So, one might say that "to keep warm" is a *sentence adverb*, as if it were transposed:
- To keep warm, several layers of thin clothing are essential.

So the answer is: both are correct, but they differ grammatically. But both are a bit vague, as neither states  *who* is keeping warm.  I might be inclined to insert "yourself":

- "{keep/keeping} **yourself** warm"

(But you might not be so inclined. That's fine too.)

I migh add, on a factual note, that with one heavy layer one CAN keep warm —but it's hard to avoid getting TOO warm!